# Efficient ways to append new data in Matlab (with example code)

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, synchronization

I am looking for methods, built-in functions, good practices... to append new data to a matrix - **when the rows and columns are not the same**

The data I deal with is structured as follows:

```
A.values: Ta x Ma matrix of values
A.dates:  Ta x 1 vector of datenum
A.id:     1 x Ma cell array of ids
```

Now the challenge is how to deal with new (potentially overlapping) data `B` that I load in and would like to append to a new matrix `C`:

When new data comes in, it can expand both horizontally and vertically due to:

- new ids
- new dates

It also can have dates that start *before* `min(A.dates)` or *after* `max(A.dates)` or *between* `min(A.dates)` and `max(A.dates)`. The ids can be all unique in B (all new) or some can be overlapping.

**Here is an example:**

```
A.values = [2.1 2.4 2.5 2.6; ...
            4.1 4.4 4.5 4.6; ...
            6.1 6.4 6.5 6.6];
A.dates  = [730002; ...
            730004; ...
            730006];
A.id     = {'x1', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6'};
```

**Now new data comes in:**

```
B.values = [1.2 1.9 1.5 1.6 1.7; ...
            3.2 3.9 3.5 3.6 3.7; ...
            7.2 7.9 7.5 7.6 7.7; ...
            8.2 8.9 8.5 8.6 8.7];
B.dates  = [730001; ...
            730003; ...
            730007; ...
            730008];
B.id     = {'x2', 'x9', 'x5', 'x6', 'x7'};
```

**How do we now efficiently and quickly construct the new struct `C`?**

```
C.values = [NaN 1.2 NaN 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.9; ...
            2.1 NaN 2.4 2.5 2.6 NaN NaN; ...
            NaN 3.2 NaN 3.5 3.6 3.7 3.9; ...
            4.1 NaN 4.4 4.5 4.6 NaN NaN; ...
            6.1 NaN 6.4 6.5 6.6 NaN NaN; ...
            NaN 7.2 NaN 7.5 7.6 7.7 7.9; ...
            NaN 8.2 NaN 8.5 8.6 8.7 8.9];
C.dates  = [730001; ...
            730002; ...
            730003; ...
            730004; ...
            730006; ...
            730007; ...
            730008];
C.id     = {'x1', 'x2', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6', 'x7', 'x9'};
```

---

**Update with timetable**

Following the comments, I tried to achieve this with `timetable` as follows:

```
function dfmerged = in_mergeCache(dfA, dfB)

dtA = datenum2datetime(dfA.dates); % function datenum2datetime can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46685634/4262057
dtB = datenum2datetime(dfB.dates);

TTa = array2timetable(dfA.values, 'RowTimes', dtA, 'VariableNames', dfA.id);
TTb = array2timetable(dfB.values, 'RowTimes', dtB, 'VariableNames', dfB.id);

TTs = synchronize(TTa,TTb);

dfmerged.id     = TTs.Properties.VariableNames;
dfmerged.values = table2array(TTs);
dfmerged.dates  = datenum(TTs.Time); %to convert datenum

end
```

Problem: However, this gave me a big timetable, where the rows where indeed synchronized, but the columns where just duplicates (9 columns). How can I also synchronize the columns?

```
C = 

  struct with fields:

        id: {'x1'  'x4'  'x5_TTa'  'x6_TTa'  'x2'  'x9'  'x5_TTb'  'x6_TTb'  'x7'}
    values: [7×9 double]
     dates: [7×1 double]
```

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? From 2016b you can use `timetable` objects and `synchronize` for this sort of thing

Comment: Ah found it :) How would such an example play out in the above? I have to transform everything in timetables? Isnt that gonna take a lot of time?

Comment: You could store your data in tables in the first place, you wouldn't need to change your code much as the table variables can be accessed with dot notation the same as structs, but things might be a bit easier; given that you basically have a table structure of headings and row data anyway

Comment: Yes, I tried it now (see update). However, keep getting the issue that my columns are not taken into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `unique` and indexing:

```
%combine the data and take unique value of them + their index
[C.id,~,date_i] = unique([A.dates(:);B.dates(:)]);
[C.dates,~,id_i] = unique([A.id B.id]);

C.values = nan(numel(C.dates),numel(C.id));
%use matrix indexing to fill the sub-materices corresponding to elements of A and B
C.values(date_i(1:numel(A.dates)),id_i(1:numel(A.id)))=A.values;
C.values(date_i(numel(A.dates)+1:end),id_i(numel(A.id)+1:end))=B.values;
```

Comment: AB is not gonna work, since they might have different number of rows. The number of rows and columns is different across A and B.

Comment: Do the values range from `1.1` to `9.9`?

Comment: No they change always. See example A vs B. The number of rows is not known in advance. Also the number of columns might differ. So we need to synchronize both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: In your example you take unique values of A and B. But they might not be always unique. You should concatenate them by unique dates and id, and not by the unique value of A or B. In my example yes values are unique. But lets say we have 2.1 also on date 730008 for x2 (replace 8.2 with 2.1 in B).

Comment: Please edit your question and explain exactly what you want with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ah come on. No need to be nut picking. I think my example is clear enough. We are dealing with time series data, it is understood that we are synchronizing dates and ids and not the values of the series...........

Comment: Thanks. But is there nothing we can do to use Matlab built in functions?

Comment: I do not know wich built-in function can be used but consider that bult-ins are not necessarily the most efficient solutions.

Comment: Hmm maybe but I prefer built-in as built-in might be more robust to unexpected situations. Your example works fine and I'll use it until I find a solution with built in functions.