# Quickest method to convert datenum to datetime in Matlab

Tags: matlab, date, datetime

I am having issue converting datenum to datetime in Matlab.

Given `dnum = [floor(now); floor(now+1)];`

I tried the following:

```
datenum(dnum)
```

But that did not work.

Ways that I found that work are:

```
datetime(datestr(dnum)) % seems slow?
datetime(year(dnum), month(dnum), day(dnum)) % slower?
```

What is the quickest way and are there better methods? Built-in functions?

Comment: Is `datetime(datevec(dnum))` any faster?

Comment: I dont know? I am looking into the best and quickest way

Comment: The doc says you can use: `datetime(dnum,'ConvertFrom','datenum')`. So that's probably the best way

Comment: Seems correct. I am gonna add an answer with the tic toc.

Comment: Maybe use `timeit`? It's more precise than `tic` / `toc`

Comment: Difference in time between methods is big enough to use tic toc (see answer)

Comment: I see. It seems to be a nice speed-up. Still, tic / toc is said to need a warm-up. This could affect timing. The first time value is suspiciously high

Comment: Understood. I tried to add two times the first one, to warm up, and there was indeed a small difference (+0.05s for the first one), but the time it took was still > 1seconds. Feel free to add your results with timeit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After experimenting with a couple of suggestions, this is the breakdown:

```
dnum = datenum(datetime(1900,1,1):datetime(2017,1,1))';
```

Then these are the results (Matlab 2016b):

```
% Elapsed time is 1.287081 seconds.
tic
dtime = datetime(datestr(dnum)); % seems slow?
toc

% Elapsed time is 0.017474 seconds.
tic
dtime = datetime(year(dnum), month(dnum), day(dnum));
toc

% Elapsed time is 0.010327 seconds.
tic
dtime = datetime(datevec(dnum));
toc

% Elapsed time is 0.000949 seconds.
tic
dtime = datetime(dnum,'ConvertFrom','datenum');
toc
```

Here is the function for copy/paste:

```
function dtime = datenum2datetime(dnum)
    dtime = datetime(dnum,'ConvertFrom','datenum');
end
```